# Static pressure inside a planet made of a fluid

Tags: potential

How can we find the static pressure at a distance r from center of the the planet made of liquid of constant density d.

My attempt:
First I tried to find the total gravitation force due to a sphere of radius r on rest of the planet.
Consider a thin spherical shell of thickness da at a distance 'a' from the center
dF = GMdm/a^3
where dm = mass of thin shell at a distance r.
Then after integrating within limits r to R we get the required gravitation force,let it be F.
Presaure = Force /area
P=F/(4*pie*r^2)
But this approach is wrong.Can anyone tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force balance for hydrostatic equilibrium is the pressure gradient balancing body forces. In your case, the body force is the gravitational force (which you already wrote) and the pressure gradient in the radial pressure gradient (dP/dr). Set the two equal and integrate.

Comment: But why this approach is wrong

Comment: Because you integrated the force first. The force balances a pressure gradient (not a pressure). So you need to balance a pressure gradient and a force and then integrate.